# How to align textboxes horizontally

Tags: css, html

i want to align two textboxes with their display names ,side by side in a single line
I am using dl,dt and dd.I am facing problem in aligining them horizontally.Could any body suggest me some idea on this alignment
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Put it up on http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Comment: Show us your code and where your problems occured.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kude9/ this is my sample code.i want to display both the fields in a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your exact case, I would set

```
float:left;
```

to dd and dt.

http://jsfiddle.net/WFzfR/

EDIT: In your fiddle, just erase clear: left; from .tm dt

http://jsfiddle.net/3hqws/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for alligning two textboxes on a single line. Below is the demo on jsfiddle. I can make out only this from your question

[Link to Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rutwik/RwYMG/)

Answer (score 0):

remove the 'clear:left' on .tm dt and they'll be on the same line

Like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/kude9/1/

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline` is usually my first attempt. If that somehow doesn't work or isn't the ideal solution, I oftenly use `float:left` just like Alvaro says.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need define a **float:left** into your  **.tm dt, dd** class because you have already defined the **display:inline** i hope you might be familiar with **block & inline elements** so inline element will come in horizontally form and will set automatically in a single row...

**CSS**

```
 .tm dt, dd
        {
            color:Black;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            display:inline;
            border:1px solid red;               
        }   
       .tm dt
        {
            padding: 0 5px 0 15px;
            text-align: right;
            opacity: 0.6;
            width: 100px;       
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tm">
  </dl>             
  <dt>Course </dt>              
  <dd>hello</dd>  


 <dt> Spl</dt>                
     <dd>hello</dd></dl></div>
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/kude9/3/